# How to wrap the content of DOM Element into another Element with minimal performance overhead?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, element

I would like to wrap the live content of a DOM element into another, keeping all the structure and all attached event listeners unchanged.

For example, I want this

```
<div id="original">
  Some text <i class="icon></i>
</div>
```

to become

```
<div id="original">
  <div id="wrapper">
    Some text <i class="icon></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Preferably without jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>If there is nothing else other than ID to distinguish your nodes, and given that `#original` has multiple child nodes, it would probably be simpler to create a new parent node and insert that:</strike>

```
var original = document.getElementById('original');
var parent = original.parentNode;

var wrapper = document.createElement('DIV');
parent.replaceChild(wrapper, original);
wrapper.appendChild(original);
```

and then move the IDs to the right place:

```
wrapper.id = original.id;
original.id = 'wrapper';
```

noting of course, that the variables `original` and `wrapper` now point at the 'wrong' elements.

**EDIT** oh, you wanted to leave the listeners attached...  Technically, they still are, but they're now attached to the inner element, not the outer one.

**EDIT 2** revised answer, leaving the event listeners attached to the original element (that's now the outer div):

```
var original = document.getElementById('original');
var wrapper = document.createElement('DIV');
wrapper.id = 'wrapper';
while (original.firstChild) {
    wrapper.appendChild(original.firstChild);
}
original.appendChild(wrapper);
```

This works simply by successively moving each child node out of the original div into the new parent, and then moving that new parent back where the children were originally.

The disadvantage over the previous version of this answer is that you have to iterate over all of the children individually.

See https://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/d0jss2yu/ for demo

Comment: Thank you! So it is not possible to keep the listeners but avoid applying multiple DOM changes in a loop?

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev I don't think so - you can put a new parent around a single child node, but I don't believe there's any way to move multiple child nodes from one parent into another without a loop.  Perhaps with document fragments?

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev *If* you can get away with the event handlers remaining on the inner element then the deleted answer should work

Comment: I need it for a general purpose library that should have no side-effects, so I need to preserve the listeners on both sides. I have looked into document fragments but it seems you still have to remove children one-by-one ;(

Answer (score -1):

<strike>**Updated answer:**</strike>

This should work better and with less code than my previous answer.

```
var content = document.getElementById("myList").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("myList").innerHTML = "<div id='wrapper'></div>"
document.getElementById("wrapper").innerHTML = content;
```

**EDIT:** This will destroy any event listener attached to the child nodes.

---

**Previous answer:**

I don't tried it, but something like this should work:

```
var wrapper = document.createElement("DIV");
wrapper.id = "wrapper";
var content = document.getElementById("myList").childNodes;
document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(wrapper);
document.getElementById("wrapper").appendChild(content);
```

1. Create the wrapper element.
2. Get myList contents.
3. Add the wrapper element to myList.
4. Add myList contents to be child of the wrapper element.

Comment: This is insufficient - there are multiple child nodes of `#wrapper`

Comment: and this will completely destroy any attached event listeners.  Using serialisation (`.innerHTML`) to manipulate DOM elements is almost always wrong.  It should only be used to create brand new elements.

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively, do it this way. It also displays result in the adjacent result div.

```html
<div id="original">
  Some text <i class="icon"></i>
</div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">do it</button>

<p type="text" id="result"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var org = document.getElementById("original");
  var i = org.innerHTML; //get i tag content
  var wrap = document.createElement("div"); //create div  
  wrap.id="wrapper"; //set wrapper's id  
  wrap.innerHTML= i //set it to i tag's content  
  org.innerHTML=""; // clear #orignal first
  org.appendChild(wrap); //append #wrapper and it's content
  
  var result = org.outerHTML;
  document.getElementById("result").innerText = result;
}
</script>
```

Comment: same problem as Gerard's answer - *never* use serialisation to move DOM elements around.  It destroys any event handlers those elements had.